# How to make JBoss accessible using IP?

Tags: jboss5.x

My JBoss server is running in my system and trying to access it from other system using ip address of my system, but its not accessible and even from my own system i am not able to access using ip.
How can i make jboss enable using ip address.

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We can run JBoss as ./run.sh -b 127.0.0.1 or run.bat -b 127.0.0.1

 This will make JBoss accessible using ip.

Answer (score 1):

If the JBoss is running on your machine you can access it using this URL

```
http://localhost:<portnumber>

If you have started the JBoss using the command 

run.bat> 

then you can access the JBoss through above URL only.

If you use this command to start the JBoss :

run –b 0.0.0.0.> 

 then you can access the JBoss using this URL also

http://<ipaddress>:<portnumber> 

In addition to this, if in place of IP address if you want to use some domain name then add that domain name 

<IP address>  <domain name> 

into the host file at this path:

C:\WINDOWS\system32\drivers\etc> 

then you can access your jboss through this url

http://<domain name>:<portnumber>
```

For more details you can check this blog http://tarunjain-jaintarun.blogspot.com/2012/08/acessing-jboss-using-ipaddress.html